# Nodejs socket write to all connections

Tags: node.js, sockets

I have a socket server in node. When it revives a new message, it writes it to the socket. But from which it has revived, writes to the corresponding socket, not all connections.

Server.js

```
var server = net.createServer(function(sock){

    console.log('new client connected');

    sock.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('Server received');

        // ** NOT sending to all clients **
        sock.write('broadcasting to others...');

    });

});
```

Client.js

```
var client = new net.Socket();

client.connect(PORT, HOST, function() {
    console.log('Client connected to: ' + HOST + ':' + PORT);
    // Write a message to the socket as soon as the client is connected, the server will receive it as message from the client 
    client.write('Client is connected!!');

});

client.on('data', function(data) {    
    console.log('Client received: ' + data);
});
```

How can I broadcast one client message to all other clients?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Following up on my suggestion to use a `Set` to keep track of all the connected sockets, this is one way to implement that.  This implementation maintains that `Set` as connections come and go by listening to both the `connect` event and the `end` event.

This implementation also supports a desirable feature to send to all connected sockets EXCEPT the one that triggered the event (which I think is what your situation would want):

```
// Set of all currently connected sockets
const connectedSockets = new Set();

// broadcast to all connected sockets except one
connectedSockets.broadcast = function(data, except) {
    for (let sock of this) {
        if (sock !== except) {
            sock.write(data);
        }
    }
}

const server = net.createServer(function(sock){
    console.log('new client connected');
    connectedSockets.add(sock);

    sock.on('end', function() {
        connectedSockets.delete(sock);
    });

    sock.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('Server received');

        connectedSockets.broadcast(data, sock);
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks. It was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can always keep the socket reference for each client in an array when they established connection to the server. To broadcast, simply loop the array and use perform the `write()`

```
var clients = [];
var server = net.createServer(function(sock){

   console.log('new client connected');
   clients.push(sock);

   sock.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('Server received');
        for(var i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) clients[i].write('broadcasting..');
   });

});
```

Or if you have the control on both server and client, I think it is better to use `websocket` or `socket.io` as it offer broadcast feature.

Comment: If you're going to keep track of all current connections, you also have to remove items from the `clients` array when they disconnect.

Comment: @jfriend00 You mean I must remove them on `onclose` event? How should I know which index I must remove?

Comment: @vahidnajafi - If it's a simple array, then you have to search the array (probably with `.indexOf()` for the matching `socket` to find the right index to remove.  Personally, I'd probably use a Set object, not an array since order is not important and the Set makes adding, removing and iterating an item easy.

Comment: if u want to keep track, using object is better as @jfriend00 recommends. set a property to the socket before storing it, like     socket.name. then to store set that name as the key and the socket ref as the value.

Comment: @Binbo - I didn't recommend using a plain object.  I recommended using a Set object which allows you to just add the socket directly to the Set - no need to coin a name for it.